# Using DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in a script in subfolder

Tags: python, django

In order to populate the database of my Django application, I created a small script that reads a CSV (a list of filenames) and creates objects accordingly:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
import django
django.setup()
import csv
import sys
from myapp.models import Campaign, Annotation


campaign_name = "a_great_name"
path_to_csv = "filenames.csv"

with open(path_to_csv) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    filenames = [i[0] for i in reader]

new_campaign = Campaign.objects.create(name=campaign_name)

for i in filenames:
    new_annotation = Annotation(
        campaign=new_campaign,
        asset_loc = i)
    new_annotation.save()
```

I saved this script at the root of my project: `myrepo/populator.py`
and it worked fine.

… until I decided to move it into a subfolder of my project (it’s a bit like an admin tool that should rarely be used): `myrepo/useful_tools/import_filenames/populator.py`

Now, when I try to run it, I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'`

Sorry for the rookie question, but I’m having a hard time understanding why this happens exactly and as a consequence, how to fix it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the problem arose when you changed the script location because then the root directory was not in the `sys.path` list anymore. You just need to append the root directory to the aforementioned list in order to be able to load the `settings.py` file of your project.

If you have the script now in `myrepo/useful_tools/import_filenames/populator.py`, then you will need to go back three folders down in your folders tree to be back in your root directory. For this purpose, we can do a couple of tricks using the `os` module.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, *[os.pardir] * 3)))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import django
django.setup()

print('loaded!')
# ... all your script's logic
```